# Proof of Uncountable Basis for $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, set-theory

Does anyone have a simple proof of the uncountability of bases of the vector space of all functions $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$. I have seen a proof which uses the determinant of the Vandermonde matrix to show the linear independence of functions of the form $f_c=c^n$ but I believe that there might be a simpler one that doesn't require the use of matrices.

I have attached a link of another proof that I found online but I find the use of the limit unsettling.
https://minhyongkim.wordpress.com/2013/10/23/a-vector-space-of-uncountable-dimension/

Comment: Zorn's lemma gives you the existence of a basis. Not the fact that it is uncountable.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of finding an uncountable linearly independent set of functions which implies that the bases cannot be countable.

Comment: And Zorn's lemma would help you how?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I think he simply mean that Zorn's Lemma guarantees that every linearly independent set we find is a subset of a basis.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a diaginalisation argument.

Let $\{f_i\}$ be a countable set we find $g\not \in span \{f_i\} $.

Construct $g$ as follows.

Look at the vector $$(f_0(0), f_0(1))$$ define $(g(0),g(1))$ not to be a linear multiple of this vector. 
Now look at the vectors

$$(f_0(2), f_0(3), f_0(4))$$ 
$$(f_1(2), f_1(3), f_1(4))$$ define $(g(2),g(3),g(4))$ not a linear combination of these vectors. Now look at the vectors 
$$(f_0(5), f_0(6), f_0(7),f_0(8))$$ 
$$(f_1(5), f_1(6), f_1(7),f_1(8))$$
$$(f_2(5), f_2(6), f_2(7),f_2(8))$$

define $(g(5),g(6),g(7),g(8))$ not in the span of these three vectors, etc. I think the construction in clear, and $g$ is not in the span. Thus there is no countable basis.

Comment: That's a nice argument!

Comment: Sry i can't see how g is not in the span.

Comment: @JhonDeo: If it's in the span, then by definition is has to be in the span of _finitely many_ of the $f_i$s. And there's a sequence of elements of $g$ that have been chosen explicitly _not_ to be in the span of the first $n$ vectors, for any $n$.

Comment: @JhonDeo $g$  not in the span of $f_0$ since the first two coordinates of $g$ is not a multiple of the first two of $f_0$. $g$ is not in the span of $\{f_0,f_1\}$ since the coordinates $g(2),g(3),g(4)$ is not in the span or the same coordinates for $\{f_0,f_1\}$ etc.

Comment: @Henning Makholm, what does mean "not to be linear multiple of this vector"?

Answer (score 8):

There are uncountably many functions $\mathbb N\to\{0,1\}$. Well-order them all, and then remove each one that is a (finite) linear combination of vectors that come *earlier* in the well-order. The result is, by contruction, a linearly independent set in your vector space. How large is it?

I claim that each of the removed vectors is not just a linear combination of vectors that remain, but a *rational* linear combination of such vectors. In each case, when we express the new vector as a linear combination of finitely many already-accepted ones, we have to solve an equation involving a matrix that is infinitely tall but has finite width. But because all elements are either $0$ or $1$, there are actually only finitely many *different* rows in the matrix, so we can find the coefficients by doing ordinary finite-dimensional linear algebra over $\mathbb Q$.

Now, if the reduced set of $0,1$-vectors were countable, there would be only countably many different finite rational combinations of them -- but this contradicts the fact that there are uncountably many vectors to express.

So we have an *uncountable* linearly independent set in your vector space, and if we extend that to a basis, we get an uncountable basis.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have a proof with Zorn's Lemma, but probably you like this one aswell:

The space you consider contains $\ell^\infty$, the space of bounded sequences, so if we can show that this space has an uncountable base the same is true for the space of all sequences.

The space $\ell^\infty$ can be made a Banach-space if we consider the supremum-norm on it. But infinite dimensional Banach-spaces can't have a countable Hamel-Base which is due to Baire's theorem.

If $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ was a Hamel-base of $\ell^\infty$ then $\ell^\infty = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\operatorname{span}(b_1,...,b_n)$. Baire's theorem tells us that one of the sets in the union has nonempty interior, thus is all of $\ell^\infty$ because it is also a subspace. This is a contradiction because it would make $\ell^\infty$ finite-dimensional.

Comment: Thanks I have seen this proof. However, I try to avoid such proofs as i have not learnt stuff like Banach Spaces and Hamel-base

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is the following, find a norm which makes the space complete   and then uses baire theorem. Zorn's lemma implies that exist a basis, baire theorem implies it must be uncountable

Comment: How do you find such a norm?